# MySQL - Get first non empty result from multiple where clauses

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, is it possible to set up a query which returns the first non empty result from a set of WHERE clauses. For instance if I have a table

```
|id  |a   |b   |
----------------
1     2    3
4     5    6
7     8    9
```

where these columns are UNIQUE, I would like to have a query ALMOST like

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE id = NULL OR a = 2 OR b = 6
```

that only returns the first row to match against any of the OR clauses in order of `id` `a` `b`, almost like a COALESCE.

Here are some example queries and expected results

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = 7 OR a = 99 OR b = 3 --> (7, 8, 9)
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = 7 OR a = NULL OR b = NULL --> (7, 8, 9)
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = NULL OR a = 5 OR b = 77 --> (4, 5, 6)
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = NULL OR a = NULL OR b = 6 --> (4, 5, 6)
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = 1 OR a = 5 OR b = 9 --> (1, 2, 3)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Im not sure what is your question because your data doesnt have any `id = NULL` can you add more rows and specify the desire output and more test cases

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I added some more example results

Comment: You need an order login. For example in your third example: `ID IS NULL OR a = 5 OR b = 77` What happen if you have two rows `{NULL, 5, NULL}` and `{NULL, NULL, 77}` which row will you show ?

Comment: We should show the `{NULL, 5, NULL}` row because it matches the `a` column which should have priority over the `b` column

Comment: Then why you havent accept juergen answer?

Comment: I am still trying to make sure it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE id IS NULL 
   OR a = 2 
   OR b = 6
order by case when id IS NULL then 1
              when a = 2 then 2
              when b = 6 then 3
         end
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by coalescing if `id` is the primary key of your table:

```
SELECT * FROM t 
WHERE id IN 
(SELECT COALESCE ((SELECT id FROM t WHERE id IS NULL),
        COALESCE ((SELECT id FROM t WHERE a = 2),
                  (SELECT id FROM t WHERE b = 6))))
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM t 
WHERE id IN 
(SELECT COALESCE ((SELECT id FROM t WHERE id = 7),
        COALESCE ((SELECT id FROM t WHERE a = 99),
                  (SELECT id FROM t WHERE b = 3))))
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```

where this assumes what you mean by "first row" is the one with the lowest `id`.

Comment: What I meant by first row is the first row that matches any of the where constraints in order of `id` `a` `b`